# merge two jsvalues dynamically and map to the child in play scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework, jsvalue

I have the following:

```scala
x = [{"value":"cricket","key":"sports"},{"value":"hockey","key":"c"},{"value":"maharastra","key":"states"},{"value":"haryana","key":"states"},{"value":"facebook","key":"company"},{"value":"google","key":"company"}]
y = [{"Id":"India","label":"sports"},{"Id":"India","label":"states"},{"Id":"usa","label":"company"}]
```

For each label of Id of jsvalue(y) is mapped to key in in another jsValue(x), I want to map those to form below structure:

```json
{
    "Mergedjson": [
        {
            "label": "India",
            "children": [
                {
                    "label": "Sports",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "value": "Cricket",
                            "enable": false
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "hockey",
                            "enable": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": "sates",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "value": "maharastra",
                            "enable": false
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "Haryana",
                            "enable": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "USA",
            "children": [
                {
                    "label": "companies",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "value": "google",
                            "enable": false
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "facebook",
                            "enable": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

All I can think of is to directly merge these jsons where I end up with having one single `jsValue`s of both x and y but not the above mentioned structure.

Comment: Sure Alok! Happy coding! Will you accept my answer?

Comment: @TomerShetah how can I replace both key value pair of jsObject, in this case if I want to replace "enable": false to "key": yes help me out. TIA

Comment: Alok, what is 'yes'? It is not a valid json value. What do you mean?

Comment: @TomerShetah, I have a JsObject "value = [{"Label":"x","Children":[{"Label":"y","Value":"y1","Children":[{"Label":"z","Value":"z1","Children":[]}]}]}]" I want to replace "Children":[] with "enable": false

Answer (score 1):

We'll start from defining `X` and `Y`, and their formatters:

```scala
case class X(value: String, key: String)

object X {
  implicit val format: OFormat[X] = Json.format[X]
}

case class Y(Id: String, label: String)

object Y {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Y] = Json.format[Y]
}
```

Then, assuming we parsed `x` and `y` successfully:

```scala
val xs = Json.parse(x).validate[Seq[X]].getOrElse(???)
val ys = Json.parse(y).validate[Seq[Y]].getOrElse(???)
```

We can first create `subLabels`, from `xs`:

```scala
val subLabels = xs.groupBy(_.key).map {
  case (value, s) =>
    val values = s.map(x => JsObject(Map("value" -> JsString(x.value), "enable" -> JsFalse)))
    value -> JsObject(Map("label" -> JsString(value), "children" -> JsArray(values)))
}
```

And then use it to create the labels themselves:

```scala
val labels = ys.groupBy(_.Id).map {
  case (id, s) =>
    JsObject(Map("label" -> JsString(id), "children" -> JsArray(s.map(_.label).flatMap(subLabels.get))))
}
```

The final json will be:

```scala
val result = JsObject(Map("Mergedjson" -> JsArray(labels.toSeq)))
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dxbm96MBR5CPBc5X4pWfog).

Answer (score -1):

Play itself and play json espicially not a best thing to work with but something like this will work:

```scala
val x: JsArray = ???
val y: JsArray = ???

val y1 = y.value.map{x => (x \ "key", x)}.toMap 

val x1 = Json.toJson(x.value.map{obj => 
  val v = obj.asInstanceOf[JsObject].values.toMap
  Json.toJson(v.updated("Id", y1(v("Id"))))
})
```

and i would advice you to throw play json to window and use circe instead.